# Looking for city names using regex in Python/pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas of strings that contains some random string of letters, followed by a potential city and state. However, the spacing is irregular.

For example, the column that I'm interested in parsing looks like

```
blah burlingtonvt
blahessex vt
blah dover vt
blahnorthchittendenvt
blah essex junctionvt
```

replacing each "blah" with some string of alphanumeric characters (potentially different for each row) that I want to preserve and with hundreds of thousands of observations and with cities and states all over the continental US. Since the state code always appears at the end, I can extract it easily with a regular expression like

```
(ny$|tx$|vt$|...)
```

where the '...' is just the rest of the states as you would expect. I then process each subset of the DataFrame for each state separately. I have a list of all possible "mis-spacings" of the cities for a given state that I've made into regular expression. i.e.,

```
x = '(essex[ ]{0,1}junction|north[ ]{0,1}chittenden|essex|...)'
```

The number of city name variations in this regular expression sometimes runs into the thousands. I then run the following line

```
df['city'] = df['string'].str.extract(x, expand=True)
```

which returns

```
  string                  state   city
1 blah waterbury cenvt    vt      waterbury
2 blah waterbury vt       vt
3 blah waterbury vt       vt
4 blah vt                 vt
5 blah shelburne vt       vt
6 blah waterbury vt       vt
7 blah richmond vt        vt      richmond
```

but if I run, for example,

```
df['city'] = df['string'].str.extract('(waterbury|shelburne|richmond)', expand=True)
```

The results are as desired. Why would this be the case? I generate the regular expression programmatically so I want to say that this isn't because of a typo. Is there a chance that it's because there're too many things to look for? Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: it turns out that there was an empty string hiding among the thousands of city names that I didn't think would be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [5]: lst = ['waterbury','shelburne','richmond']

In [6]: pat = '({})'.format('|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in lst]))

In [7]: pat
Out[7]: '(\\bwaterbury\\b|\\bshelburne\\b|\\brichmond\\b)'

In [8]: df['string'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
Out[8]:
           0
0  waterbury
1  waterbury
2  waterbury
3        NaN
4  shelburne
5  waterbury
6   richmond
```

Comment: What's '\b' and why do we need to use raw strings? Are you using raw strings exactly because there's a '\b'? I'm actually running into another problem that could use this as the solution.

Comment: @user49007, [`\b` - is a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). I used raw strings for convenience, so i don' thave to care of escaping special (RegEx) symbols